# set Trianglify js for a SVG background

Tags: svg, trianglify

i want to set Trianglify js for a SVG background but i can't.
i can set for a div with the following codes :

```
        var something = document.getElementById('portfolio');
        var dimensions = something.getClientRects()[0];
        var pattern = Trianglify({
            width: dimensions.width,
            height: dimensions.height,
            x_colors: ['#444', '#555', '#666', '#777', '#888', '#999'],
            y_colors: 'match_x',
        });
        something.appendChild(pattern.canvas());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** If you want to generate a trianglify design to use as your SVG background, you can use their [Trianglify Generator](http://qrohlf.com/trianglify-generator/). You can customize the pattern/design you want and then export to SVG or PNG.

---

Here's some info from the Github [docs](https://github.com/qrohlf/Trianglify#patternsvgopts).

And from their main site:

```
var pattern = Trianglify();

//SVG DOM node
pattern.svg();
```

Comment: no no i have a svg and i want to set trianglify for this svg background

Comment: Do you want to generate a trianglify pattern/design and then save it as svg or png to use as your svg background?

Comment: I updated my answer above. See where it has the bolded "Edit". :)

Comment: i want to use trianglify for this svg background : https://jsfiddle.net/bv99Lexd/

Comment: Yes, so use the generator and then replace your source with the new trianglify pattern you just created...